# Bootstrap navbar dropdown does not open

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The dropdown menu in the navbar which build by bootstrap does not open.

 Do you have any solutions?

 here is the code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <!--JQuery.min.js------------>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <!--JQuery.min.js------------>


        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: Please specify the exact problem instead of specifyin just a link to the HTML page..Show us what you have done..

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: You have errors! "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
http://web.freeserv.co.il/js/bootstrap.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"...

Comment: but i use CDN why do i need this files? and how can I get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still having the issue put `http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js` before

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`in `head`.

Like this:

```
 <head>
-----
-----
----
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!--JQuery.min.js------------>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<!--JQuery.min.js------------>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Hope this help you.!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Jquery file for boostrap.first load the Jquery file then load boostrap file  .then u won't get error it will work

[image: enter code here]